# Catalyst + mod_perl + selenium: how to Devel::Cover?

Tags: perl, catalyst, mod-perl, devel-cover

I have a web application with lots of tests. I am currently only using Devel::Cover for coverage reports of my unit tests, but would also like coverage reports of my front-end Selenium tests.

I have tried 'use Devel::Cover' in my app psgi startup file. This creates the cover_db directory, but it remains empty while running my Selenium tests.

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: How do you do the coverage for the unit tests? Are those using Catalyst::Test?

Comment: For unit test coverage I do the following: PERL5OPT="$PERL5OPT -MDevel::Cover" prove t/Unit

Comment: I don't know how mod_perl works, but you probably can set environment variables somewhere. Set that same one where you spin up the server. That might work.

Comment: @simbabque, as far as a general answer goes it is probably great. ;-) Unfortunately I have tried doing this in the apache conf file and the psgi startup file and this does not generate coverage data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Plack::Middleware::Profiler::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::Profiler::NYTProf)

From the synopsis

```
use Plack::Builder;

builder {
    enable 'Profiler::NYTProf';
    [ '200', [], [ 'Hello Profiler' ] ];
};
```